# Add data annotations to members in derived class

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a solution which is composed out of several projects. One of these projects is a container for POCO objects, shared between all the other projects. Because the objects need to be compatible with Windows Phone, Silverlight, Windows Apps, etc. it's created as a shared library with only a subset of references.

I want to re-use these objects for a code-first implementation of a database model, which requires I add data annotation attributes to the members. But the data annotation namespace is not contained in the reference subset.

So I thought I'd create derived classes in my service API project, to add the data annotations there. But I'm not quite sure how to do this or if it even can be done.

So I'm looking for some ideas, maybe best practices. Of course I could create new models and use a mapping technique to get data from one to the other, but when they're 100% equal that sounds a bit foolish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [MetadataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx)?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]
public class DerivedEntity : PocoEntity
{
   private sealed class Metadata
   {
      [Required, AnotherAnnotation]
      public object NameOfPropertyToDecorate;
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
This doesn't work. If you add the `MetadataType` attribute to the base class, it works; if you add it to the derived class, the annotations are ignored. This behaviour feels like a bug, but there might be a reason for it.

Your best option is probably to use [the fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591617) to configure your entities.

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PocoEntityConfiguration());
   }
}

public class PocoEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PocoEntity>
{
   public PocoEntityConfiguration()
   {
      Property(e => e.TheProperty)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasMaxLength(80)
         ...
      ;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work because it works the other way around. This approach needs you to declare the MetadataType on the POCO itself, pointing to the other class which holds the metadata. I need to extend the class in a different project which references the POCO, not the other way around.

Comment: @Jasper: It seems like adding the `MetadataType` attribute to the derived class *should* work, but unfortunately, at least in .NET 4.0, it doesn't. Adding the attribute to the base class does work, so this is probably a bug. It seems like your only option is to use the fluent configuration API.

Comment: Hello Richard, my opinion still stands; I cannot specify any attributes on the POCO because they would need to point to the class defining the metadata, which would be in the other project. The dependencies are the other way around; the project with the metadata is dependant upon the project holding the POCO.

Comment: I'll look into the fluent config API, haven't seen that before. Thanks.

Comment: Late reply, but here it is! I've acheived it using Fluent API which works great. I now have a seperate project with only POCO's which references the .NET Portable Subset (i.e. works on all devices). In the datalayer project I have a reference to the shared project and use Fluent API to add entity configuration like primary keys, required fields and such. Works great!